# Using Twitter Bootstrap col-sm-2 and col-sm-10 breaks <a> tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In creating a sidebar with an outline, my goal is to have a small left column and a large right column wrapped in a styled link that the user can click in order to access the assignment document.

This works as far as wrapping all the text, but there aren't any columns, just the data appearing centered over the document name:

```
<a class="assignment" ng-href="#/course/{{state.course.id}}/lesson/{{$parent.$index}}?    page={{$index}}">
  <div class="text-center assignment-due">
   <p>
      {{page.due_date | todayDate: 'EEE'}}
    </p>
    <small>
      {{page.due_date | date:'MMM dd'}}
    </small>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4 class="assignment-name">
      <b>Assignments</b>
      {{page.name}}
    </h4>
  </div>
</a>
```

However, the following causes the box representing the styled link to appear some distance above the text and date, on top of other items (even though the columns show up correctly:

```
<a class="assignment" ng-href="#/course/{{state.course.id}}/lesson/{{$parent.$index}}?page={{$index}}">
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center assignment-due">
    <p>
      {{page.due_date | todayDate: 'EEE'}}
    </p>
    <small>
      {{page.due_date | date:'MMM dd'}}
    </small>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <h4 class="assignment-name">
      <b>Assignments</b>
      {{page.name}}
    </h4>
  </div>
</a>
```

I have tried moving the  link around, adding extra  tags, etc., but as long as the col-sm-X tags are there, the  link doesn't wrap the text.

Any ideas other than abandoning Twitter Bootstrap in favor of some other way to get columns?

Thanks!

Update:  With both assignment and discussion (defined identically to assignments) objects in the outline, this is what it looks like:  [image: borked outline]

Update #2: This is working for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/LVdBv/11/

Comment: Is this what you trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/LVdBv/

Comment: The items are part of a <ul> <li> object (on a higher level).

Comment: Lowkase, yes, that's what I'm working for.  However I want the whole orange-yellow thing to be wrapped in a lightgray associated with the <a> classes (row, assignment).  Removing the yellow/orange and adding this to the css:  .row {background:lightgray;}  doesn't have any effect?

Comment: Please update the fiddle to demonstrate the problem better, then add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

According to html standards, `<a>` is an inline-level tag and you cannot put block-level tags like `div` or `ul` inside it. By skipping these rules, your code will be invalid and you may face problems in some browsers.

I think I managed to fix your problem by changing your HTML code and using css to style elemetns:

```
<div class="row">
    <a class="assignment" ng-href="#/course/{{state.course.id}}/lesson/{{$parent.$index}}?page={{$index}}">
        <span class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 lft">
            <span class="assignment-name">
                <b>Assignments</b>
                "Hey, Hey Baby"
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 text-center assignment-due rgt">
            <span class="day">
                Tue
            </span>
            <small class="date">
                Jan 15
            </small>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
a.assignment { display: block; }
a.assignment > span { display: inlin-block; }
a.assignment > span span { display: inline-block; }
.day { display: block; }
.assignment-name b { display: block; }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LVdBv/7/

fiddle preview: http://jsfiddle.net/LVdBv/6/embedded/result/

Comment: I updated some things here:  http://jsfiddle.net/LVdBv/10/ to make the text more like what I need, but why isn't the text in the result yellow?

Comment: It's now yellow because it doesn't have height and that's because it's contents are floated to left. putting a `clearfix` will clear the floats and make `.assignment` yellow: http://jsfiddle.net/LVdBv/12/